# How to extract every string between two substring in a paragraph?

Tags: python, string, substring, extract, innertext

After web-scrapping, I get the following:

```
[<p>xxx<p>, <p>1.apple</p>, <p>aaa</p>, <p>xxxxx</p>, <p>xxxxx</p>, <p>2.orange</p>, <p>aaa</p>, <p>xxxxx</p>,<p>3.banana</p>, <p>aaa</p>, <p>xxxxx</p>]
```

From the list, "xxxx" are those useless values. I can see the pattern that the result I want is between two substrings. Substring1 = "<p>1" / "<p>2" / "<p>3" ; Substring2 = "</p>, <p>aaa".

Assume this pattern repeats hundreds of times. How do I get the result by python? Many thanks !!

My target result is :

1. apple
2. orange
3. banana

I have tried to use split and tried [sub1:sub2] but it doesn't work

Comment: you would be way better off posting the actual html snippet than this contrived version.  In fact It is likely that this process you are asking about isn't even necessary if you are using the right scraping tools and methods

Comment: As @Alexander said: 'this pattern repeats' is not clear enough; I imagine the beacons are `<p>number.` but knowing what `number` can be would help answer...

Answer (score 0):

From what I INFER from your question (assuming the words you're looking for follow a beacon of format `<p>number.` ), a regex would do the job:

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'<p>\d+.([^<]+)', html_string)

# ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
```